# How to match the first word before a pattern and the pattern itself in regex?

Tags: regex

Looking for a regex to match the bracketed timestamp and the first word directly before the timestamp.

`Joe: [00:00:00] Hello Bob. Bob: [00:00:00] Hello Joe.`

Match should be `Joe: [00:00:00]` and `Bob: [00:00:00]`

I'm able to match the bracketed timestamp but having difficulties matching the first word before it. Here is what I've done so far which matches the timestamp: `\[\d+:\d{2}:\d{2}\]`

How can I also match the first word before the timestamp and the timestamp itself?

Comment: Use this: `\S+\s*\[\d+:\d{2}:\d{2}\]`

Comment: can you add a check that the first word must end with a colon?

Comment: Use `\w+:\s*\[\d+:\d{2}:\d{2}]`

Comment: `\w+: *\[\d+:\d{2}:\d{2}\]` or `\w+: *\[[^]]*]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `regex` expression:

```
^\S+\s*\[\d+:\d{2}:\d{2}\]$
```

By adding `$` at the end, you are sure that the expression ends the timestamp bracket.

By adding `^` at the start, you are sure to not include the letters before the white space.